# SQL - Insert Duplicate Rows to New Table then Delete Duplicate Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table I need to insert duplicate records in another table. And I need to delete it from the first table.

And the code I've found is like this:

```
WITH q AS 
(
    SELECT a.* FROM SampleData AS a
    LEFT JOIN SampleData AS b ON 
    a.Name = b.Name AND 
    a.Account= b.Account AND
    a.Amount = -b.Amount 
    WHERE b.Name IS NOT NULL
)
DELETE FROM q OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO SampleData2
```

The problem now is it returns an error:

> View or function 'q' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.

Any help on this? I can't find a way to solve this error.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `EXISTS`.

```
WITH q AS 
(
    SELECT a.* 
    FROM SampleData AS a
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM SampleData AS b
                  WHERE  a.Name = b.Name 
                    AND  a.Account= b.Account 
                    AND  a.Amount = -b.Amount)
)
DELETE FROM q OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO SampleData2
```

Comment: . Sorry for the late response. It works great! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
WITH q
AS (SELECT
        a.*
    FROM
        SampleData AS a
        LEFT JOIN SampleData AS b
            ON a.Name = b.Name
            AND a.Account = b.Account
            AND a.Amount = - b.Amount
    WHERE
        b.Name IS NOT NULL
)
DELETE s
    OUTPUT Deleted.* INTO Sample2
FROM 
    SampleData s
    JOIN q
        ON s.Name = q.Name
        AND s.Account = q.Account;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the CTE below picks out the duplicates:

```
WITH q AS 
 (
 SELECT a.* FROM SampleData AS a
 LEFT JOIN SampleData AS b ON 
 a.Name = b.Name AND 
 a.Account= b.Account AND
 a.Amount = -b.Amount 
 WHERE b.Name IS NOT NULL
 )

SELECT * INTO NEWTABLE FROM q --Takes duplicates from CTE and inserts into a table called NEWTABLE

DELETE FROM FIRST_TABLE 
WHERE NEWTABLE.Column = FIRST_TABLE.Column --Or whatever matches to help you delete the duplicates
```

Hope this helps!